# AngularJS ui-router not loading template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My AngularJS app doesn't find the template `landing.html`, although I tried to make the correct declarations everywhere.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
@@include('partials/head.html')
<body>

  @@include('partials/header.html')

    <main class="content">

      <ui-view></ui-view>

    </main>

  @@include('partials/footer.html')
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      url: '/',
        controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing',
        templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html'
    })
      .state('faq', {
      url: '/faq',
      templateURL: 'faq.html'
  });
    $locationProvider
        .html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

The structure of my files is as follows:

```
/src
|
|--index.html
|--faq.html
|--js
|  |--main.js
|  |--controllers
|  |  |--LandingCtrl.js
|--templates
|  |--landing.html
```

I think the path for `landing.html` is correctly declared, but I'm still getting the following error:

`angular.min.js:sourcemap:123 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$compile/tpload?p0=templates%2Flanding.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found`

Would anyone have an idea as to why the app can't find the template?

**EDIT**
When I enter this in the browser URL:
`http://localhost:3000/templates/landing.html`

Result is:
`Cannot GET /templates/landing.html`

**EDIT 2**
Removing `$locationProvider` also removes the "landing.html not found" error msg, but the view that's supposed to be rendered inside of `<ui-view>` is still not shown.

Comment: What appens if you remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });` ?

Comment: why are you using `locationProvider` ? you can run the app without locationprovider

Comment: I thought I needed `$locationProvider` because I have a "back to top" link down at the bottom of the page, on which I had implemented the Angular `$anchorScroll` in `LandingCtrl.js`. I understand that if I don't use this (or don't declare `HTML 5 mode` in it), the app will add an extra symbol to page-internal links; I believe such as `#!`.

Comment: but if you remove the `#!` it can't find your view

Comment: which url you are using to render the view?

Comment: Forgive me, but do you mean a URL such as: `localhost:3000/landing.html`? Because `landing.html` is supposed to be rendered inside of that view when I go to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Actually, I expect the view to just appear when I enter the URL `localhost:3000`. Or pls let me know what you mean by URL being used to render the view @TejinderSingh

Comment: unless you are compiling your html, you need to include the full path. /whatever/src/templates/landing.html

Comment: @yBrodsky by "full path" do you mean the absolute path on my drive? The "app" starts at `src`. Later I will move these files to my host webserver, so would I again have to adjust the absolute pathnames?

Comment: relative to your app. If src is a root folder, then you start at src/etc/etc

Comment: @orlando21 try using this `localhost:3000/index.html/#!/landing`

Comment: Thanks. When I type that into the browser, I get an error: `Cannot GET /index.html/` But how would I code that into the app? Typing `http://localhost:3000/index.html` however does display the app... minus that view that's supposed to be rendered within `<ui-view>`.

Comment: @orlando21 try using this `localhost:3000/#!/landing`

Comment: @Tejinder Singh no luck with that either. Do you think I need to try to declare the view for example with: `angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router', 'myApp.landing'])` ?

Comment: @orlando21 do you have skype id?i can check over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151294/discussion-between-tejinder-singh-and-orlando21).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in your `index.html` change `<ui-view></ui-view>` to `<div
  ui-view></div>`.

in your `main.js` change the code as below:-

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      url: '/landing',
        controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing',
        templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html'
    });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');

}])
  .run(['$http', '$templateCache', function($http, $templateCache) {

    $http.get('templates/landing.html', {
      cache: $templateCache
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: Should also mention that I am using grunt, so I changed `Gruntfile.js` to  copy the template file into `/dist`, which wasn't done previously.